# @google-cloud/logging causing Error: Could not load the default credential

Tags: firebase, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, winston

I am getting this error when trying to use `@google-cloud/logging` with Firebase Functions. If I remove the logging stuff everything works fine. I also tried using `@google-cloud/logging-winston` however, causing the same error along with an additional error.

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Tag = require('../../models/tag')
const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging')

const logging = new Logging({projectId: 'circle-fc687'})
const log = logging.log('tags')
const METADATA = {
    resource: {
        type: 'cloud_function',
        labels: {
            function_name: 'tags-getTags',
            region: 'us-central1'
        }
    }
}

const uri = 'mongoURL'


module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('getTags : start')
        const logOne = log.entry(METADATA, { event: 'getTags:mongodb:started', value: 'started', message: 'tags-getTags:started' })
        log.write(logOne) // I've also tried with an await here thinking maybe it was trying to do something after the function terminates but that didn't fix anything

        console.log('getTags : after first logging statement') // doesn't work

        await mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

        const result = await Tag.find({})

        res.send(result)
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err)
    }
})
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/srv/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:161:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Edit 1: adding `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^6.0.0",
    "@google-cloud/logging-winston": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.9.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.3",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Which node version are you targeting, 8 or 10?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've tried with both

Comment: Could you add your package.json here?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yup, see Edit 1

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a clue .... https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup ... what pricks my ears is "Access Google Cloud Platform resources like Cloud Storage buckets and Cloud Firestore databases associated with your Firebase projects.".  GCP stackdriver logging might be considered a "GCP resource" and by this bullet, may require that we add Firebase Admin SDK to the Cloud Function mix.

Comment: Another thought is this recipe ... https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firebase-cloud-functions-logging-aggregation/     What I notice about this one is that in the Logging() constructor, no projectId parameter is supplied.  A wild guess might be that if you supply one parameter you have to supply them all (including credentials).

Comment: @Koban the admin SDK is mostly just a wrapper around existing GCP SDKs. It doesn't provide anything for logging. Also, with pretty much every GCP SDK, constructing a new object by default should take the default settings from the Cloud Functions environment.  There might be something wrong with the environment, or a bug/incompatibility in the version of @google-cloud/logging SDK being used here.

Comment: Try going back to version 5.5.5 of the logging module just to see if something maybe broke in 6.0.0 withe respect to Cloud Functions and the Firebase SDKs.  If  it works, then look into filing a bug somewhere.

Comment: @DougStevenson Giving the version change a shot now. If there's something wrong with the environment itself, is that something I have any control over?

Comment: @DougStevenson Not really sure what to make of this, but regardless of which version I use it seems as though when I first deploy the functions it gives me this error, but after a few minutes if I try again then everything seems to work. Is there some sort of cache update or further configuration that has to happen even after the deploy from my local machine is complete?

Comment: I don't know.  Bear in mind that sometimes it takes a while to fully deploy a change.

Comment: Right, this is a curious one. Thanks for them help